# No such element exception in machine learning pipeline using scala

Tags: scala, machine-learning, apache-spark, pipeline

I am trying to implement an ML pipeline in Spark using Scala and I used the sample code available on the Spark website. I am converting my `RDD[labeledpoints]` into a data frame using the functions available in the SQlContext package. It gives me a `NoSuchElementException`:

Code Snippet:
[image]

Error Message:
[image]

Error at the line `Pipeline.fit(training_df)`

Answer (score 0):

The type `Vector` you have inside your for-loop (`prob: Vector`) takes a type parameter; such as `Vector[Double]`, `Vector[String]`, etc. You just need to specify the type you data your vector will store.

**As a site note:** The single argument overloaded version of `createDataFrame()` you use seems to be [experimental](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.scala#L430). In case you are planning to use it for some long term project.

Comment: I changed that line. Now, I am getting a new error. I have updated my question with the new error.

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline in your code snippet is currently empty, so there is nothing to be fit. You need to specify the stages using `.setStages()`. See the example in the spark.ml documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#example-pipeline).